# returning html saved as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, variables, dojo

I am working with Dojo data grid row expansion. [Example here.](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_expand.html)

I am trying to put another grid inside the part that expands. Here, I create the grid container and append the grid to it

```
gridDiv = document.createElement('div');
gridDiv.setAttribute('class','blah');
gridDiv.appendChild(grid2.domNode);
```

Later on, I am trying to print that div out on the page by returning `gridDiv`.

```
return gridDiv; //gives me "[object HTMLDivElement]" in the expanded section
return gridDiv.HTML; //gives me "..." in the expanded section
return String(gridDiv); //gives me "[object HTMLDivElement]" in the expanded section
```

How do I get it to actually put the div element with the grid inside on the page? I can not use the jQuery library, but I can use the Dojo library.

Thanks for any help you can give! I feel like I'm missing something very obvious...

/**BREAKTHROUGH**/
I used `gridDiv.innerHTML` as a variable and returned THAT in the code. However, now it is printing out the HTML in plain text... I've got to figure out why it is not parsing now.

Comment: sometimes libraries like this store the relevant data in a div that is hidden somewhere else, maybe use something like firebug to see if that data is even in the div?  Or if it is in the div, maybe everything but the ... is hidden.

Comment: yes, when I look inside the `<td>` the only thing that is there is the ... or the string `[object HTMLDivElement]`

Answer (score 1):

Try using dojo.place

```
// Dojo < 1.7
dojo.place(node, refNode, pos);
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/place.html

Comment: no matter how i format `dojo.place`, it gives me some sort of `"appendChild is not a function"` error in the console. is this because of the way i'm trying to use `return`?